# Using Linq to get the last N number of rows that have duplicated values in a field

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Given a database table, a column name `C`, and a number `N` larger than 1, how can I get a group of rows with equal values of column `C` which has at least `N` rows? If there exists more than one such group, I need to get the group which contains the newest entry (the one with the largest Id).

Is it possible to do this using LINQ to Entities?

```
Example:

> Id | Mycolumn
> - - - - - - -  
> 1 | name55555
> 2 | name22
> 3 | name22
> 4 | name22
> 5 | name55555
> 6 | name55555
> 7 | name1

Primary Key: ID
OrderBy: ID
Repeated column: Mycolumn
```

If `N = 3` and `C = Mycolumn`, then we need to get rows which have the column `MyColumn` duplicated at least 3 times.

For the example above, it should return rows 1, 5 and 6, because last index of `name55555` is `6`, and last index of `name22` (which is also repeated 3 times) is `4`.

Comment: Define "duplicated rows" in this context? Because if they are *identical* (which suggests you don't have a primary key etc), then **why fetch more than one?** - they are *identical*

Comment: Not all of them are Identical just one field,I updated my question.

Comment: Please provide an example of actual data, and then indicate which rows you would consider "duplicated". "Last N" ordered by what? Can you have multiple different groups of such row? Your code snippet doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: @Groo, you are right,I edited the question

Comment: Row 5 is also repeated with row 2. So why do you expect the query to return `{4 6  7}`? Should it not return `{5 6 7}`? The question is is not clear at all! :(

Comment: @ANeves, no It shouldn't because name2 is not even duplicated 3 times and name5 is the last row which has duplicated more than tree times.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.Mytable
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Id)
    .GroupBy(m => m.Mycolumn)
    .FirstOrDefault(group => group.Count() >= N)
    .Take(N)
    .Select(m => m.Id)
```

Comment: I cant see how `Reverse` would be supported for a SQL provider for linq since tables are unordered.

Comment: @Groo Since there is a `GroupBy` after the `order by` the provider will just drop the order by statement in the generated SQL. (since order by is not supported for sub queries in SQL)

Answer (score 1):

If the rows are *identical* (all columns) then frankly there's no point fetching more than one of each - they will be indistinguishable; I don't know about LINQ, but you can do something like:

```
select id, name /* more cols */, count(1) from @foo
group by id, name /* more cols */ having count(1) > 1
```

You can *probably* do that in link using `GroupBy` etc. If they aren't entirely identical (for example, the `IDENTITY` is different, but the other columns are the same), it gets more difficult, and certainly there is no easy LINQ syntax for it; at the TSQL level, though:

```
select id, name /* more cols */
from (
select id, name /* more cols */,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name /* more cols */ order by id) as [_row] 
from @foo) x where x._row > 1
```

Comment: I meant duplicated values in a field not all columns

Comment: @farhang67 the second example above example shows a single field... `name`; just make sure you only `partition by` the single field...

Comment: @ANeves actually they should both work, but: I would put good money on the above generating a saner execution plan than LINQ can come up with ;p

Answer (score 1):

I have scratched this together in Linqpad, which should give you the wanted results:

```
int Border = 3;
var table = new List<table> 
{
  new table {Id = 1, Value = "Name1"},
  new table {Id = 2, Value = "Name2"},
  new table {Id = 3, Value = "Name5"},
  new table {Id = 4, Value = "Name5"},
  new table {Id = 5, Value = "Name2"},
  new table {Id = 6, Value = "Name5"},
  new table {Id = 7, Value = "Name5"},
};

var results = from p in table
              group p.Id by p.Value into g
              where g.Count() > Border
              select new {rows = g.ToList()};
//only in LP
results.Dump();
```

this yields the rows 3, 4, 6, 7.

However: You only want the last occurence, not all, so you have to query results again:

```
results.Skip(Math.Max(0, results.Count() - 1)).Take(1);
```

Kind regards

Comment: OP doesn't need to ignore the first value, you should just return the group containing the largest `Id`.

Comment: then he made an error in his very first example. I will edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: It works,Thank you so much. but one problem here is that what if we don't know how many times it has duplicated totally to use skip 1

Comment: I think I have a problem in my code. I still need to check for the highest Id, which would determine the last duplicate which is there.